# Plasmashell keeps crashing [KUBUNTU]

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I get

[image: this message]

every few minutes on Kubuntu (KDE), and the panels disappear.

It restarts itself automatically, so it's not a real problem, just an annoyance, but it is a big annoyance.

I've tried *sudo apt install --reinstall plasmashell plasma-desktop*, but that made no difference.

When I try a backtrace from the error message, it says it's unable to produce a useful backtrace.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 4 gigs. I plan to upgrade when I have the means. Is that the problem?

Comment: I get the same issue constantly but my panels remain...

Comment: Look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/773703/constantly-crash-kubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Ubuntu version, KDE Version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, KDE 4.14.16

Answer (score 6):

Try installing the latest version of Plasma as a backport:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

Comment: Has this helped?

Comment: @Supernormal This is how I solved the issue

Comment: Seems to have worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have any non-standard plasma widgets, I would try to remove those.

Then, I would kill `plasmashell` process and then run it from the command line to see the full debug output.

to get a useful backtrace you need to install the *-dev related packages.

about widgets:
potentially removing your whole panel, or widgets on your background and recreating a new panel if you want. is an option.

finally, you could inspecting your local plasma related config files.

```
$ find .config/ | grep plasma
.config/plasma-localerc
.config/plasmavaultrc
.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
.config/plasmanotifyrc
.config/plasmarc
.config/plasmawindowedrc
.config/plasmawindowed-appletsrc
.config/plasmashellrc
.config/plasma-nm
```

you could back them up and move them away between restarts. I would start by `.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`

hope this helps