# Plasma constantly crashes in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I have pretty much the exact same problem as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900308/plasmashell-keeps-crashing-kubuntu/949008). Re-posting this as a separate question since I can't comment and was advised to do so.

For me, the crashes happen most often when I hover the mouse over a panel launcher that has an open window. This is almost *guaranteed* to crash Plasma with the same dialog as shown in the linked question.

I've tried Aidan's suggestions in his answer to that question and will wait a week to see if that helps, but in the meantime I'd really appreciate any more info that the community can provide. MTIA! :D

Comment: You should've have waited to see whether the backports work for you or not. As of now, your question is a bit premature and "any more info that the community can provide" is vague. BTW, feel free to sign up at https://www.kubuntuforums.net which is a bit more flexible and more suited to this type of situation.

Comment: @DKBose - My apologies; I will remember that for next time and will definitely sign up at kubuntuforums.net. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: OK it's been a week and it seems as though Aidan's solution has worked! I will upvote his answer to the other question accordingly.